setQueryTimeout is not working with Hive JDBC
I have the following code:
try  {
    Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://...");
    int queryTimeout = 1;

    queryStatement = con.prepareStatement("select reflect(\"java.lang.Thread\", \"sleep\", bigint(10000))");
    queryStatement.setQueryTimeout(queryTimeout);

    rs = queryStatement.executeQuery();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("QUERY_ERROR=" + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Using version 3.1.3000.7.1.7.2032-1 and the code ends OK nothing thrown
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-4924?jql=project%20%3D%20HIVE%20AND%20text%20~%20setQueryTimeout
Looks like it should be supported, am I doing something wrong?
